# Using a foreign key with django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Hello I have two tables that I defined such as :

```
class Test(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=True, default=None)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=4096, null=True, default=None)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Water, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

with the following entries :

```
title content user_id
a     b       1
d     e       2
```

```
class Water(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=True, default=None)
    color = models.TextField(max_length=4096, null=True, default=None)
```

with the following entries :

```
id name color
1   q    s
2   f    g
```

But I noticed in my database I have a field which has the name of user_id...

Do you know for instance if I want to do a query how can I do ?

For instance if I define this :

```
test = Test.objects.get(user=?).title
```

How can I do to do a filter on user like it is user_id instead of user ?

Thank you very much

Comment: You haven't really explained what you are trying to do or where your problem is. If you have a user object, you can use it directly where your `?` is.

Comment: Actually I would like to filter on title = a and get the color associated in my case s

Comment: So what does that have to do with the foreign key?

Comment: Well, what I want is just an example which filter on the foreign key a basic example to see how it works

Comment: It is really not clear what you are asking. Filtering on a foreign key is no different from anything else. Exactly where are you having problems?

Comment: [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)'s the docs, read them. You'll see you just use the python representation. `test.user` is a `Water` object. Filter with `Test.objects.filter(user=some_user)` where `some_user` is a `Water` object. In your db, django is using `user_id` and integers to make the queries, but you should just use `user` and `Water` objects in most scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

from this statement

> what I want is just an example which filter on the foreign key a basic example to see how it works

I think you are trying to do something like:

```
test = Test.objects.get(user__color='red')
color = test.user.color
```

Here I am using get to get single record, you can use filter and itereate the queryset to get the output.

You can check the Django Docs for [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey)